# Right approach to convert a word document that contains forms in a web app

Tags: code-generation

I would know if someone can suggest a good approach to convert a word document that contains forms in a web app, specifically in an application built with WaveMaker.(but I'm curious also with a general approach not strictly dependent on the technology that I have mentioned).
For example, if I have a page in a word document, that maps the fields of a user entity, what could be my "programmer approach" to convert it without much use of copy-paste, but with a dynamic methodology ?

Comment: What platform are you running your web-app on?  If it's WaveMaker (or other java-based) server, look at apache POI.  A .NET solution would be a possible way to go if your platform supports it.

Comment: After read the word document with apache POI, according to you, can be used a code generator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) is a set if libraries providing a Java API for working with Microsoft-type documents.  It's not going to code-generate anything for you (or be generated), but you might be able to build a service around POI that your web app could then use to pull the fields out of your documents.